# Fake email address with comment

Tags: comments

Someone is claiming that, there was a comment on their WordPress website made by a friend of mine which was derogatory. Their proof is a screenshot of the comment, which shows my friend's work email address, ipv6 address and an alias. They're trying to get them sacked over this comment. The IP address in the screenshot doesn't geolocate to the right location for it to be them, and I'm convinced it wasn't them. I'm unaware if this is a self hosted wordpress install or not.

I'm assuming the screenshot is of the administration panel where the user can approve comments. Apparently the WordPress instance requires the user to login to submit comments.

Ignoring that a screenshot isn't probably proof that should be used to sack someone. As a software engineer, I know that there's a database behind this and if someone got access to it, they could update the email address used in a comment.

But does anyone know of another, simpler method on WordPress to use an arbitrary email address for a submitted comment? Such as changing the email address of the account after posting the comment (without validating the new email).

Comment: If some has access to the site files and database almost anything is possible, but this really isn't the place for this sort of question. It's not regarding development and no one here is going to be able to prove or disprove what's happening on some other unidentified site.

Comment: additionally to add to Jacobs comments to teach someone how to perform a shady task just is not what this site is all about.